Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \cos(e^x)$
We have a theorem for Uniform continuous  functions
A function $f : A \to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ if and only if for all sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) in A such that when $\lim_{x\to\infty}|x_n − y_n| \to 0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x_n) − f(y_n)|\to 0  $.
Given a function $f(x) = \cos(e^x)$
A) To prove its uniform continuity
I considered two sequence such that
$x_n = \log n + \frac{1}{n}$
$y_n = \log n$
Such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}|x_n − y_n| \to 0$
$|f(x_n) − f(y_n)| = |\cos(ne^{\frac{1}{n}})-\cos(n)|$
But $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\cos(ne^{\frac{1}{n}})-\cos(n)|$
doesn't approached zero.
B) But when I take other sequences, such as
$t_n = log(2n\pi) + \frac{1}{n}$
$w_n = log(2n\pi)$
Such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}|t_n − w_n| \to 0$
$|f(x_n) − f(y_n)| = |\cos(2n\pi + \frac{1}{n})-\cos(2n\pi)|= |\cos(\frac{1}{n})-1| $
than
$\lim_{x\to\infty}|\cos(\frac{1}{n})-1| \to 0$
I can't understand where I am mistaken!

In $(A),$ aren't you disproving uniform continuity?

And your definition is wrong at the start. You need it true for all sequences $x_n,y_n$ with $|x_n-y_n|\to0,$ not just one pair of such sequences.

A clearer disproof for $(A)$ would be $x_n=\log(2\pi n)$ and $y_n=\log((4n+1)\pi/2).$

Yeah thank you I edited the question. It's  "for all" sequence.

But I am still confused. This function is uniformly continuous.  In A) the sum of two sequence at infinity goes to zero. But why then |f(xn) - f(yn)| not approaching to zero.

It is not uniformly continuous. Why do you think it is?

In part B,  |f(tn) - f(wn)| approaches zero.

Uniform continuity needs it true for all pairs of sequences. If one pair 9f sequence doesn't satisfy this, the function isn't uniformly continuous.

The theorem should be '... is uniformly continuous on $A$
if and only for every two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ in $A$ such that $|x_n−y_n|\to 0$ then $|f(x_n)−f(y_n)|\to 0$ ', otherwise we could just take $x_n=y_n=0$ and conclude every function is uniformly continuous.
Precisely the two sequences you propose at A) prove that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
